# Can <span>'s vertical borders be made to overlap?

Tags: css

When nesting multilple spans within each other with a border, by default, their horizontal (top and bottom) borders overlap, and their vertical (left and right) borders stack.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4un9tnxy/

`.html:`

```
<span><span>a</span> + <span>b</span></span>
```

`.css:`

```
span { border: 1px solid black; }
```

You can set `display: inline-block;` which will make all borders stack.

Is there a way to rig it so that all borders overlap?

Comment: I think it is not possible. What is your goal? Maybe different solution will be better.

Comment: Only solution I see: `span > span { border-right: none; }`.

Answer (score 0):

A border can only be drawn around what a tag contains.

However, you can write additional CSS to remove the boarders of nested spans.

### CSS

```
/*Border for span*/
span {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

/*Remove nested span borders*/
span > span {
    border-style: none;    
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/jsallans/4un9tnxy/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of  ugly code but something like this might help you:
https://jsfiddle.net/4un9tnxy/4/

```
span {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

span span span:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

To reflect what you mentioned in the comment below, here is a slightly more generic version: https://jsfiddle.net/4un9tnxy/6/

```
span {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

/* for spans inside of spans */
span span {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I should have been more clear, this solution is too specific, I'd like it to work for arbitrary nestings.

Comment: @Ptival, I added a more generic version that disappears borders on the right side of descendant spans. Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a better approach for you even though it's not with a span it produces a better result. It doesn't work in jsfiddle for some reason but works in browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
   </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-right: -1px;` also.

```css
span {
border: 1px solid black;
margin-right: -1px;
}
```

```html
<span>a <span>b <span>c</span></span></span>
```